# How to transfer ownership of a synchronization object in C++ or Winapi?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mutex, critical-section

Is it possible to transfer the ownership of a mutex, critical section etc. from the first thread to the second thread without letting any third thread to grab ownership in the meantime?
The [documentation for critical section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684169(v=vs.85).aspx) prohibits to call LeaveCriticalSection in a thread other than the one who called EnterCriticalSection:

> If a thread calls LeaveCriticalSection when it does not have ownership of the specified critical section object, an error occurs that may cause another thread using EnterCriticalSection to wait indefinitely.

But in my scenario I need to exactly release the synchronization object in a different thread than the one who acquired it, so that no other (third) thread can acquire the ownership of the synchronization object in the mean time (from the moment of acquisition by the first thread till the moment of release by the second thread). A solution in C++ threading or WinAPI calls would be suitable for my needs.

Comment: shouldn't `std::move` work?

Comment: @deW1 A CiriticalSection is a Windows OS object, not a C++ class.

Comment: You could do this with a second critical section (or other sync object) that guards the transfer between the two. Hard to get right without the risk of deadlocks though. Are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: @deW1, "std::mutex is neither copyable nor movable" from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex . Furthermore, std::move is about moving objects in memory, not about moving synchronization objects between threads. E.g. unique_lock is movable (in memory with `std::move`, but it doesn't seem to allow to move the mutex between threads).

Comment: There are a few points in your posts that are unclear but if I had to guess I think what you are looking for are win32 event object.
You can wait on it and set the event from another thread.
If not then please clarify what is the state of the thread who acquired the section and why can't he release the critical section?
How do you know that thread isn't in the middle of a possible race condition that the critical section was meant to prevent?

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I don't see an easy way to do that with the second critical section. The first thread still needs to leave the first critical section, and the second thread still needs to enter the first critical section. So who will be owning the second critical section, when will it be entered and left?

Comment: `But in my scenario I need to exactly release the synchronization object in a different thread than the one who acquired it` - Critical section simply is not designed for that usage. You can use other synchronization mechanism, e,g, [semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438(v=vs.85).aspx): it doesn't have  *ownership* semantic, so it can be released by any thread.

Comment: @Jonathan, yes, an auto-reset event seems more appropriate in this scenario: the first thread waits for the event, after this thread acquires the event no one else can acquire it too, then the first thread passes the handle to the event to the second thread, and after the second thread does the work it can release the event (set it back to signalled state).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, thread owenership transfer is not supported. Moreover, I firmly believe that any design which depends on lock ownership is flawed and will cause troubles down the road.

However, if ownership transfer is required only for releasing a lock from a thread different from the one receiving it, you have two options:

- Use semaphores. By design, they are allowed to be released from any thread
- Enagage in undefined behavior and release a mutex from the thread which doesn't own it. You need to understand consequences of this.

**Undefined behaviour**

Releasing a mutex from the thread which doesn't own it is undefined. However, it is possible to code your application with those. The problem you will have is that data synchronization might not happen on non-cache coherent chips if the thread which locked the mutex was running on one CPU, and unlocking happens on another. As a result, the data which was not protected by another synchronization will be 'dirty'. However, if there is no such data - for instance, mutex is trully used in a 'semaphore' fasion and does not protect any data - this might be acceptable.